# Importing the BrowserModule into a standalone Angular16 project

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components, angular16

Angular 16 is recently released and I have created a new standalone project without any module.
then in a standalone component I need to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `angular/platform-browser/animations`. but when I import it, this error occures:

> Poviders from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded.  If you
> need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the
> `CommonModule` instead.

and when I remove it this one:

> Unexpected synthetic listener @animation.start found. Please make sure
> that: Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are
> imported in your application.

so why first error occures? where is BrowserModule already loaded? and if it has already been imported how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `provideAnimations()` for this !

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
      provideAnimations()
    ]
 })
```