# Angular 16 standalone url always routs to home page

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

My Angular 16 app is pure standalone, no ng modules at all.
I configured routes, and when used within components as links (e.g.: routerLink="/team") it routes to the correct page, and the URL changes accordingly.
However, trying to reach a page directly from the URL (for example, by just refreshing the `localhost:4200/team` page) - renders the home page. The URL does not even change - /team still appears as the URL, but the rendered page is the home page.

These are the relevant files:

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-top-nav></app-top-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

(If I remove the `app-top-nav` and `app-footer`, then the behavior does not change, only the URL indeed changes to `/home` as well).

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DatabaseService, EmailService } from 'src/app/services';
import { UnsubscribeGroup } from './interfaces/unsubscribe-group.enum';
import { FilterMatchMode, PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { TopNavComponent } from "./components/top-nav/top-nav.component";
import { FooterComponent } from "./components/footer/footer.component";
import { CookieHandlerService} from "./services/cookie.service"

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, HttpClientModule, TopNavComponent, FooterComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService, private emailService: EmailService, private cookie: CookieHandlerService, public primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig, private router: Router) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.primengConfig.ripple = true;
    
    this.primengConfig.zIndex = {
      modal: 1100,    // dialog, sidebar
      overlay: 1000,  // dropdown, overlaypanel
      menu: 1000,     // overlay menus
      tooltip: 1100   // tooltip
    };

    this.primengConfig.filterMatchModeOptions = {
      text: [FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH, FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS, FilterMatchMode.NOT_CONTAINS, FilterMatchMode.ENDS_WITH, FilterMatchMode.EQUALS, FilterMatchMode.NOT_EQUALS],
      numeric: [FilterMatchMode.EQUALS, FilterMatchMode.NOT_EQUALS, FilterMatchMode.LESS_THAN, FilterMatchMode.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO, FilterMatchMode.GREATER_THAN, FilterMatchMode.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO],
      date: [FilterMatchMode.DATE_IS, FilterMatchMode.DATE_IS_NOT, FilterMatchMode.DATE_BEFORE, FilterMatchMode.DATE_AFTER]
    };

this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  } 
}
```

Trying to remove the last line: `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` has no effect.

**main.ts:**

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { enableProdMode, importProvidersFrom  } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  PreloadAllModules, 
  provideRouter, 
  withDebugTracing, 
  withPreloading, 
  withRouterConfig 
} 
from '@angular/router';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

**app.config:**

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  PreloadAllModules, 
  provideRouter, 
  withDebugTracing, 
  withPreloading, 
  withRouterConfig 
} 
from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient() ]
};
```

**app.routes:**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { TeamComponent } from './pages/team/team.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './pages/signup/signup.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './pages/terms/terms.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from './pages/privacy/privacy.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, 
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent }, 
    { path: 'team', component: TeamComponent }, 
    { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent },  
    { path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyComponent },  
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyDreamTeam</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**What am I missing, please?**

Comment: Can you please share working example with code to check your issue?

Comment: Hi Kinjal. What do you mean by working example? The URL remains in /team (or /signup, or any routed page) but the content in <router-outloet> is the home page. This is when going to /team directly in the browser URL.

Comment: please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217757/importing-the-browsermodule-into-a-standalone-angular16-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my top-nav.component.ts, I was importing this module:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Removing this import (from the imports array of the component) - solved the problem!

You can see this in the stackblitz provided above. URL:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kvfyb5?file=src%2Fmain.ts

https://stackblitz-starters-kvfyb5.stackblitz.io/

Remove the BrowserAnimationsModule import in the top-nav component - and the problem goes away.
This works in my local implementation as well now.

In Stackblitz, you can see that the console throws this error if this import exists:

```
Error: NG05100: Providers from the BrowserModulehave already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import theCommonModule instead.
```

Problem is, in my local setup, this error is not showing in the console, so I had no idea!
So, couple of takeaways:

1. Some errors are not showing locally, while they do show in Stackblitz.
2. This BrowserAnimationsModule probably conflicts with something and cannot be used in some situations. See in Stackblitz...